# Angular: Resource in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-resource

I try to build a 'selectCategories' directive with AngularJS. The HTML element itself is more or less a simple select field but I want to load the options from a RESTful service. Therefore I built a 'Categories' Service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.services')

    .factory('Categories', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/categories/:id.json', { id: '@id' }, { 'query': { isArray: false }});
    });
```

Now I want inject the 'Categories' service into the 'selectCategories' directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')

    .directive('selectCategory', function(Categories) {
        // --> Request all the categories.
        return {
            restrict: 'E'
        }
    });
```

It's possible to do it but it feels wrong to inject a service which requests the RESTful service. Has someone experience with it? Maybe there are better ways to do it.

Comment: You can set up a controller for the directive and inject the Service into that instead. Then set a variable on the scope of the controller for the categories and bind to that variable in the directive template. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think it's safe to use a service directly in your directive. Your logic is clearly seperated, and your directive shouldn't care about where the data comes from.